# Sample "Phoneword" project - Empty app view on deploy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

The title says it all, I was just beginning learning Xamarin and installed VS Community 2015 and Xamarin.Android. I was guided by [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/) link.

I started the sample project, the Phoneword app flashed on my Android 5.1 Oppo but not with the elements (e.g. Text Field, Button, etc).

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this happen on other devices / emulators? It might help if you're able to share a link to your project on GitHub so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It just happened that Visual Studio by default comments out the line of code that set the main layout as the current Activity layout. Its now working all fine except that I need to find another software for the emulator because its taking me forever to boot one. Thanks!

Comment: Every time after you debug an android app, you close the emulator? Usually with VS, we just need to boot a emulator for the first time until you close it.

Comment: No i don't close. In fact the emulator stuck up to the android screen and never gets me to the launcher. I ended up using my real phone. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please tell me which emulator are you using?

Comment: Yes sure i downloaded Xamarin for VS and it comes with SDK, NDK and AVD..

Comment: @Jim If you're using the Google AVD then ensure you have the HAXM driver installed, and that you're downloading the x86 images for each API level. The ARM images will perform poorly in comparison.

Comment: Thanks @Alan but unfortunately my HP Pavilion laptop dont support HAXM. I guess id just have to stick with using my phone for debugging.

Comment: @Jim Unless it's quite old then it probably should.  You might need to enable virtualisation (or similar) in the BIOS.  Also, ensure Hyper-V is turned off.

Comment: Hi @AlanClark i can play DotA 2 on this laptop and its CPU is core i5 with 4GB ram, i also enabled virtualization from BIOS but not sure how to turn off hyper-v. Also debugging thru phone takes approximately 45 seconds just so you could see your updates from the moment you hit F5 from VS

Comment: Download the HAXM directly from intel.